# Dynamically add content to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty good understanding of HTML and CSS (including Bootstrap), I feel I'm ready to have some user interaction, and adding dynamic content to my html pages.

My question is, where do I start to learn to achieve this?

For example, what languages do I need to learn to dynamically add news articles to a specific webpage? I can obviously include articles in the code (using a mixture of heading and paragraph elements), but obviously that would require a redeployment of code every time a change is made.

Any help and/or direction of helpful sites would be very grateful.

Comment: Learn Javascript ( google MDN theyve got good tutorials)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Everything else (jquery,nodejs etc.) is based on that

Comment: Thank you @Jonasw. I'll start to learn about JS then go from there, but do you by chance have any examples of adding user comments to a webpage?

Comment: Not for a bloody beginner. Try it yourself. Thats the best way to learn. Come back to StackOverflow if you get stuck. Then i help

Comment: Also for blogging etc you may learn PHP (but JS first!!)

Comment: That makes sense @Jonasw, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic language of client-side interaction is JavaScript. Definitely start with native **JavaScript**, as in just the language itself.

After that, you have a lot of frameworks to choose from that use JS like **JQuery** and **AngularJS** to name the two that seem most relevant to what you want to achieve. Each have their quirks, but all are written in JS or **EcmaScript** so after obtaining a foundation in JS, its just a matter of learning the framework rather than syntax.

I advise you to learn with online demo or courses. You can make a lot of things with this language but he's free so you must avoid learning to use it incorrectly.

- [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)
- [Article about learn JS](https://colorlib.com/wp/learn-javascript-online-free/)
- [JS Frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)

Comment: "Use" better "are written in"

Comment: Thank you @Alexis. I'll start with JS then go from there.

Comment: I'd recommend VueJS after you're comfy with JS. You can learn it in a day or two. Angular will have you learning for the next 6 months. (not knocking Angular, but if you want to just get going, Vue is better.